# Alternating increasing sequence

Tags: c, recursion, sequence

Morning-

I need a function that would produce the following kind of looking sequence:

```
1, -1, 2, -2, 3...
```

Would a tail recursive function be the best way to handle this? Is there  a way  to do this iteratively as opposed to recursively?

Comment: Recursion is more memory costly

Comment: I agree, that's why I was trying to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Recursion is pretty much *always* the wrong solution to a problem unless the number of levels is bounded by log(n)...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sequence has a trivial non-recursive form:

```
A[n] = (n + 1) / 2 - (n % 2 ? 0 : n)
```

depending on indexing.

Comment: you can optimize with: A[n] = (n+1)>>1 - (n&1 ? 0 : n)

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL correct, but most compilers will apply that optimisation for you, so it's usually not worth making the code less clear.

Comment: If `n` is unsigned, the compiler can do it for you. If `n` is signed, the "optimization" does not yield the same behavior, so the compiler cannot do it for you. Thus, making it explicit can sometimes be useful.

Answer (score 3):

```
return (n>>1) * -(n&1);
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach would be to use [`abs()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/abs/) function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i-- > -10) printf(" %d %d", i, abs(i));
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, a simple function like below can help. You need to write some more code if you want to do something more to it.

```
void calc_sequence(int *arr, int size)
{
   int i=0;
   int j=0;


    for(i=1; i<=(size/2); i++)
    {
      arr[j] = i;
      arr[j+1] = -i;
      j = j+2;
    }
 }


 /* The below code should come in the calling function. n is the maximum positive number you plan to see in the sequence */

   int *arr = malloc((n*2) * sizeof(int));
   calc_sequence(arr, (n*2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use build your sequence iteratively.

```
int *
f(size_t size)
{
    int *p = malloc(size * sizeof *p); // Checks for overflows

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        p[i] = (i + 1) / 2;
        if (i & 1) p[i] -= i;
    }

    return p;
}
```